# Unerwartete Wortreihenfolge mit dem Wort "genannt"

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

Meine Frage betrifft den folgenden Satz, einen Ausschnitt von *Katzenwiege* von Kurt Vonnegut (also die deutsche Übersetzung von *Cat's Cradle*).

> Und ich bin so gut wie sicher, daß während meines Gesprächs mit Dr. Breed in Ilium der gerade aufblühende *Wampeter* meiner *Karass* jenes kristallisierte Wasser war, jener bläulichweiße Edelstein, jener Same des Untergangs, **genannt *Eis 9***.

(Wie man sehen kann, enthält der Satz ein paar vom Schriftsteller erfundene Wörter, die kursiv gedruckt sind.)

Am Ende des Satzes, bekommen wir eine Liste alternativer Beschreibungen für "jenes kristallisierte Wasser". Die letzte auf der Liste ist "genannt *Eis 9*." Warum wurde das nicht in umgekehrter Wortreihenfolge geschrieben, also "*Eis 9* genannt"? Normalerweise würde man "Das Ding war *Eis 9* genannt" sagen (abgesehen davon, dass es vielleicht unidiomatisch wäre), oder? Oder missverstehe ich etwas?

Comment: Es kann nicht gleichzeitig das sein, was man sagen würde und undiomatisch.

Comment: Ha, stimmt. Ich habe nur gemeint (und das war bei meiner Frage noch lange nicht klar), dass ich nicht weiß, ob "genannt wurde" oder "gennant war" idiomatisch ist. Das weiß ich immer noch nicht, da beide viele Treffer bei Google bekommen. Also vermute ich jetzt, dass beide gehen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Grundstruktur dieses Satzes ist eine Nominalphrase, die eine Partizipialkonstruktion als Apposition hat.  Das kann man generell immer machen, hat aber manchmal spezielle Idiomatik.  Zb. die "Rezeptform"

> - Nüsse, gehackt
> - Mehl, gesiebt

Wenn die Partizipialkonstruktion selbst Argumente enthält, stellt sich die Frage der Reihenfolge.  Grundsätzlich kommen hier normale Einflüsse der Informationsstruktur zum Tragen:

> Das ist Zwetschgenmarmelade, für sechs Stunden eingekocht.
>
> Das ist Zwetschgenmarmelade, eingekocht für sechs Stunden.

Im ersten Fall wird die Aussage auf das Einkochen fokussiert, im zweiten auf die Dauer.  Beide Sätze sind ziemlich gleich gängig und unterscheiden sich in der Praxis auch in der Bedeutung fast nicht.

Hier kann man die Präpositionalphrase auch durch einen Akkusativ der Zeit ersetzen:

> Das ist Zwetschgenmarmelade, sechs Stunden eingekocht.

aber die andere Reihenfolge ist interessanterweise für mich kaum akzeptabel:

> Das ist Zwetschgenmarmelade, eingekocht sechs Stunden.

Ich wüsste nicht, was grammatisch gegen die zweite Variante spricht, aber sie klingt einfach sehr komisch.  Ein Zeichen, dass zusätzlich idiomatische Konstruktionsbeschränkungen herrschen.

Genauso ist es bei deinem Beispiel.

> Jenes Wasser, Eis 9 genannt.

ist völlig akzeptabel und keine besonders markierte Konstruktion.

> Jenes Wasser, genannt Eis 9.

ist genauso akzeptabel, aber zusätzlich einen Instanz der speziellen Konstruktion *X, genannt Y*, die idiomatisch vor allem bei Namensvorstellungen gebraucht wird, etwa *Franz, genannt Frankie* oder *New York, genannt Big Apple*.

Ungeprüft vermute ich, dass die Konstruktion vorzugsweise bei Personennamen verwendet wird.  In deinem Beispiel wirkt sie deshalb angemessen, weil es eine längere, recht pathetische Aufzählung von Epitheta ist, die dann in *Eis 9* kumuliert.  Also einerseits stilistisch etwas altertümlicher anmutend, andererseits von der Fokussierung her die "richtigere" Variante.

Comment: Danke @phipsgabler, sehr hilfreich. Aber würden Sie dennoch sagen, dass die Reihenfolge bei "Das hier ist genannt Eis 9" auf keinen Fall richtig ist?

Comment: Grammatisch ist das nicht falsch, aber grenzwertig akzeptabel. Es ist auch eine andere Konstruktion, nämlich ein echtes Passiv, und keine Apposition von einem Partizip. Zur Verbesserung sollte da vermutlich ein Vorgangspassiv stehen (_wird genannt_), und andererseits ist die Reihenfolge extrem markiert. Eventuell mit Doppelpunkt, zur besonderen Betonung: _das hier wird genannt: Eis 9_.

Answer (score 2):

Bei der feierlichen Vorstellung, etwa wenn ein Moderator einen Künstler ankündigt, der gleich die Bühne betreten wird, hebt er sich den Namen, als wäre es eine Überraschung, was es meistens nicht ist, auf bis zum Schluss, genannt Höhepunkt.

> Hier kommt sie, die Stimme aus dem Moor, der flinkeste Gitarrenfinger des wilden Westens, 9facher Zappaawardwinner und Shooting Star 2021, Rudi Ratlos, genannt Todesgeiger!

Comment: "... auf bis zum Schluss ..." statt *bis zum Schluss auf* ist auch interessant und einfach eine Entscheidung für eine von zwei Möglichkeiten.

Answer (score 1):

Es ist auch im heutigen Sprachgebrauch nicht ungewöhnlich, dass der zugeordnete Name auf *genannt* folgt, siehe diese [DWDS-Korpusabfrage](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=%2C%20%40genannt&corpus=korpus21&date-start=2000&date-end=2010&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50), die nicht nur passende Treffer enthält.

Ein aktuelles Beispiel, aus Stadler, Arnold: Sehnsucht, Köln: DuMont Literatur und Kunst Verlag 2002, S. 34

> Schon am 2. Januar hatten wir gelacht über die sogenannten Bürger, wie sie in kilometerlangen Schlangen in Frankfurt am Main und anderswo anstanden, um sich das Schnupperset, **genannt Euro-Kit**, zu sichern, das später einmal, wenn sie nicht mehr lebten, sehr wertvoll sein würde.

Ein weiteres, älteres Beispiel aus der klassischen Literatur ist der Buchtitel von E. T. A. Hoffmann: [Wikipedia: Klein Zaches genannt Zinnober](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_Zaches_genannt_Zinnober)